# Inner join of images using geemap

Tags: python, geemap, pca

I have 4 indices: VCI, TCI, PCI, scaledET. I want to derive a drought index as a linear combination of these 4 indices using PCA. The idea here is to find the contribution of each of these indices to the first PC. Each of these indices is stored separately as a `'Image.tif'` based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876442/computing-normalizeddifference-using-image-collections-in-google-earth-engine), I need to combine these images as bands of a single image. I tried his solution:

```
VCI_URL = "gs://VCI/VCI_10_2013.tif" 
TCI_URL = "gs://TCI/TCI_10_2013.tif" 
PCI_URL = "gs://PCI/PCI_10_2013.tif" 
ScaledET_URL = "gs://ScaledET/ScaledET_10_2013.tif" 

VCI = geemap.load_GeoTIFF(VCI_URL)
TCI = geemap.load_GeoTIFF(TCI_URL)
PCI = geemap.load_GeoTIFF(PCI_URL)
ScaledET = geemap.load_GeoTIFF(ScaledET_URL) 

#  1. Join datasets. First, define filter. This is based on the date.

filter = ee.Filter.equals(**{
  'leftField': 'system:time_start',
  'rightField': 'system:time_start'
})

# Define an inner join.
innerJoin = ee.Join.inner()

# 3. Apply the join.
innerjoin1 =  innerJoin.apply(VCI, TCI, filter)
innerjoin2 =  innerJoin.apply(PCI, ScaledET, filter)

# # 4. Merge both collections
M1 = innerjoin1.map(lambda feature: ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary')))
M2 = innerjoin2.map(lambda feature: ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary')))
```

When I try  `M1.getInfo()` I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    329   try:
--> 330     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    331   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:

6 frames
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/value:compute?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "Join.apply, argument 'secondary': Invalid type.
Expected type: FeatureCollection.
Actual type: Image<[TCI]>.". Details: "Join.apply, argument 'secondary': Invalid type.
Expected type: FeatureCollection.
Actual type: Image<[TCI]>.">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    330     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    331   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
--> 332     raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
    333 
    334 

EEException: Join.apply, argument 'secondary': Invalid type.
Expected type: FeatureCollection.
Actual type: Image<[TCI]>.
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as simple as:

`firstImage = ee.Image.cat([VCI, TCI, PCI, ScaledET])` In my case, I don't need to do inner joins since all images already have the same time stamp.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer. It will be helpful for future viewers.